# Objective C LValue required as unary '&' operand

Tags: objective-c, pointers, stdio, scanf

In my code, I get this error when I *try* to get a pointer to my class property.
(I wrote a small *.OBJ file translator in Python, discarding the normals)
CODE:

```
//line: line of text
const char *str = [line UTF8String];  
Point3D *p1, *p2, *p3;
p1 = [Point3D makeX:0 Y:0 Z:0];
p2 = [Point3D makeX:0 Y:0 Z:0];
p3 = [Point3D makeX:0 Y:0 Z:0];
sscanf(str, "t %f,%f,%f %f,%f,%f %f,%f,%f",(&[p1 x]),&([p1 y]),&([p1 z]),&([p2 x]),&([p2 y]),&([p2 z]),&([p3 x]),&([p3 y]),&([p3 z]));
Triangle3D *tri = [Triangle3D make:p1 p2:p2 p3:p3];
```

Answer (score 4):

Are the `x`, `y`, `z` messages accessors ? I guess so. Then they are returning copy of the values (since Objective-C does not have the notion of references), and you are passing to the `sscanf` function pointers to temporaries, and thus the error.

You should use local variables to get the values from the `sscanf` function. Something like that:

```
const char *str = [line UTF8String];
float p1x, p1y, p1z, p2x, p2y, p2z, p3x, p3y, p3x;
sscanf(str, "t %f,%f,%f %f,%f,%f %f,%f,%f",
       &p1x, &p1y, &p1z, &p2x, &p2y, &p2z, &p3x, &p3y, &p3x);
Point3D *p1, *p2, *p3;
p1 = [Point3D makeX:p1x Y:p1y Z:p1z];
p2 = [Point3D makeX:p2x Y:p2y Z:p2z];
p3 = [Point3D makeX:p3x Y:p3y Z:p3z];
Triangle3D *tri = [Triangle3D make:p1 p2:p2 p3:p3];
```

Comment: Ok... But that's alot of variables... EDIT: Im going to use an array then

Comment: The other option is to make the backing ivars of those properties public. You can then use -> to get at them and take the address of them normally. This has other issues that can crop up though